# Slick2D Unexpected Error

Tags: java, slick2d

I have been making a game with Slick2D and I recently started having to use the console for debugging, and I noticed that I have been getting these errors:

```
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGDecoder.decode(PNGDecoder.java:272)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.loadImage(PNGImageData.java:97)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:62)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:43)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:292)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:187)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:192)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:166)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:154)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:132)
    at luke_r.java.project_alpha.SplashScreenInitiator.init(SplashScreenInitiator.java:27)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:171)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at luke_r.java.project_alpha.Core.main(Core.java:21)
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 INFO:Initialising sounds..
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 INFO:- Sound works
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 INFO:- 64 OpenAL source available
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 INFO:- Sounds source generated
Mon Jun 02 16:13:35 BST 2014 WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGDecoder.decode(PNGDecoder.java:272)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.loadImage(PNGImageData.java:97)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:62)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:43)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:292)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:187)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:192)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:166)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:154)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:132)
    at luke_r.java.project_alpha.ImageManager.load(ImageManager.java:14)
    at luke_r.java.project_alpha.SplashScreenInitiator.init(SplashScreenInitiator.java:30)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:171)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at luke_r.java.project_alpha.Core.main(Core.java:21)
```

I have absolutely no idea (after lots of research) what could be causing this. Please could some explain?

**EDIT:** Here is the line it doesn't like for the first error: `splash = new Image("res/img/splash.png");`
Here is the line it doesn't like for the second error: `sandMap = new Image("res/img/map/sandmap.png");`

**EDIT 2:** [Sandmap.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwFwQ.png) [Splash.png](http://i.imgur.com/GdZG2lC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still having trouble with this then I may have a solution. I use paint.net and ran into the same problem. When you save your image from paint.net a save configuration window will pop up after you choose your save destination. For me I had to change the Bit-Depth from 8-bit to 32-bit. Auto-detect will sometimes work but only if it auto detects it as 32-bit. I have not tested 24-bit, it may work as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: This appears to be the only solution that has worked for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

> org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
>
> Unsupported format for this image

The error message says what's wrong. Either your image is corrupted, or not supported, or not saved properly. What kind of image are you using?

Comment: I am using .PNG, and the image works in the code fine, it displays, I can get properties from it and everything I would normally be able to do with a picture in this context (in Slick2D).

Comment: @LemonLuke Can you upload the image somewhere and add the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

@Anubian is correct that your PNG must be corrupt.  Try remaking it or use another software to create it.  See where Slick2D threw the exception [here](https://github.com/ariejan/slick2d/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/opengl/PNGDecoder.java#L265-L273).  I tried to use Wolfgang Fellger's [PNG Analyzer](http://wolfgangfellger.de/en/product,4) and I couldn't even open your image.

Comment: But how am I meant to fix this? I made the pictures in Paint.NET and I have always used this without any problems, and it is the only good one I can find.