# Slick util error with png [with solution]

Tags: java, png, textures, lwjgl, slick2d

I've searched this site for a definitive answer to my problem but it seems that everyone has a different answer as to the origin of the problem but no specific solutions.

I'm using the Slick-Util library with lwjgl and when I load my texture file for my basic shape, the program take a bit longer to start (as opposed to being instantaneous without the texture loading) and despite the fact that I get my texture on screen, I get this error in the console (which could explain the initial loading lag)

```
Sat Mar 07 05:35:42 EST 2015 WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData failed to read the data
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
```

the code where I load the file:

```
public int loadTexture(String fileName)
{
    Texture texture = null;
    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("res/" + fileName + ".png"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int textureID = texture.getTextureID();
    textures.add(textureID);
    return textureID;
}
```

I'm using a regular png file, non-interlaced, 8 bits 256 x 256 without transparency. Any idea why i get this error, how I can prevent it and if I could use something else than slick-util that would not give me that error?

A file that works:

[image: a file that works]

and one that does not:

[image: this one does not]

Comment: Can you list the offered solutions that did not work for you?

Comment: I was using paint.net to make the texture and when switching to basic paint and making a new texture, it worked fine. I used a [png analyzer](http://wolfgangfellger.de/en/product,4) and only difference i could find with basic knowledge of how picture format works is that the paint.net image color was saved in a ?palette format? as to the regular pain image, it was using rgb format. Not sureif that's the cause of the problem tho.

Comment: @Jongware : [solution one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997911/slick2d-unexpected-error) stating that it could be a corrupt file.
[Solution two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876968/why-is-slick-giving-me-this-warning-regarding-png-data) mentioning the interlaced problem. and there's a few others I canèt get my hands on right now. Been having this problem for quite a while now.

Comment: Can you add a link to one of the image files that shows this problem?

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful. First thing I notice is your working image is *not* "8 bits", as you assumed -- it is '256 x 256 image, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced' according to `pngcheck`. And the not-working image *is* '256 x 256 image, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced'. This suggests Slick can only work with 24-bit RGB images and not with indexed colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the annoyance of having to use regular paint to draw all my textures:

1. Create the image in paint.net as usual despite the compatibility problem.
2. Select all and copy the entire image.
3. Open a new document in regular paint and paste the texture to it.
4. Save the image with regular paint as a .PNG and everythign should be working fine!

If your texture is already saved in a file that throws an error with slick utils, open it and repeat steps 2-4

Comment: I have the same compatibility issue, and the same solution!!!!.... Anything more stable?

Comment: Although this happened to me through the `paint.net` application.